# How to find the median form an ordinal (rank) variable and mode from this data-set?

Tags: statistics

Data-set:
[image]

Aside from just finding the middle number is there another way to determine the median from this data-set by just using the cumulative percentage?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The cumulative total for Level '3-Once a Month' is 40.42 % < 50%. And the
cumulative total for '4' is 56.32% > 50%, so Level '4' is the *median*
level for the categorical variable tabled.

The highest percent 22.48% is for Level '1-Not at all', so that is the
*modal* level.

Because level designations '1', '2', ..., '7' are labels, not really
numbers, it is not possible to compute a useful mean for this categorical
variable.